# Coloured texted in console/terminal

Tags: c++, cross-platform, terminal, ncurses

Using ncurses in C++, how would I colour my text in a console/terminal without breaking MinGW support? Are there any other libraries that can do this? I know that you can do it with ASCII characters, but this isn't fully supported. I don't want to use the Windows API.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion in the other answer is regarding Windows, so for the benefit of Win readers, I'm leaving this answer even though it is not cross-platform.

The Old New Thing blog [covers some of the Win32 API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/15/10090867.aspx) that can be used to change text color in the console.  See [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682662%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Console Screen Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682088%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

Comment: Although I would like it to work on windows as ubuntu is my OS I want to use something ncurses, but I can't find a good example

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to mingw implies that you expect this to work in a Windows Cmd window. Unfortunately the Cmd window doesn't support color, except globally for the whole window.

Comment: That's what I thought, would it break the program with ncurses or just show up as black text?

Comment: @Will03uk I've never tried ncurses on Windows so I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @Will03uk, my answer might not be correct. It appears that there's a direct interface to the console which does allow color coding, and I'm guessing ncurses for Windows would take advantage of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS

Comment: Maybe this is of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899341/print-coloured-text-to-console-in-c (*shameless plug*)

Comment: @Skurmedel, your solution looks good for the Windows case but the original question is for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I am blind as a bat :)

Comment: @Skurmedel that's a windows way of using colour. I want it to work and windows MAC and Linux

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for NCurses, but I have used PDCurses to do color under winXP/MSVC 6, WIN7/MSVC 2010 in a console application.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Stuff I wrote, using he PDCurses functions.

Comment: What was the exact code you wrote; PDCurses should be, as far as I believe, just about compatible, so what PDCurses code did you use??